# Can JsonPatchDocument use Attributes

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, json-patch

Can I use Attributes on my objects and still use JsonPatchDocument?

Currently, if I have this object:

```
public class Test {
        public float FloatTest { get; set; }
}
```

I can only send in float, both in a post-request and in a patch-request.

If I add an attribute:

```
public class Test {
        [Range(1, 100)]
        public float FloatTest { get; set; }
}
```

I can now, in a post-request, only send in floats between 1 and 100. In patch though, ModelState stays valid even if I patch with FloatTest = 1000.

Is there anyway to check this in the ApplyTo-function in JasonPatchDocument, or is there any other best practice I've missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TryValidateModel` to validate your data , refer to the below code :

```
[HttpPatch]
    public IActionResult JsonPatchWithModelState([FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<Test> patchDoc)
    {
        if (patchDoc != null)
        {
            var test = new Test();

            // Apply book to ModelState
            patchDoc.ApplyTo(test, ModelState);

            // Use this method to validate your data
            TryValidateModel(test);

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            return new ObjectResult(test);
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
    }
```

Result :
[image]