# C# JsonPatchDocument: Is it possible to set custom error messages when ModelState is invalid

Tags: c#, json-patch

When for example an invalid date has been entered the response message will be the following.

```
{
     "errors": {
         "AccountDto": [
             "The value '77-77-7777' is invalid for target location."
          ]
    },
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400
}
```

I want to customize these errors by returning for example `$"{propertyName} input value '77-77-7777' is an invalid date"`. For every DateTime property

Comment: you could use FluentValidator but im not sure there's a clean way to combine it with a json patch document before applying the changes to the object

Comment: maybe this will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/58537687/3608449

Answer (score 1):

Add this method to your controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Patch([FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<AccountDto> patchDoc)
{
     if (patchDoc is null) 
         return BadRequest("patchDoc is null.");

    // This is an example, you most likely have
    // a service to get the account model
    var account = new Account();
    
    patchDoc.ApplyTo(account, ModelState);
    
    TryValidateModel(account);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
        return UnprocessableEntity(ModelState);
    
    //Save changes...
    
    return NoContent();
}
```